# Логирование действий пользователя в веб приложении spring

Tags: java, spring

Я ученик. Мне дали тестовое задание (первое, которое я выполняю). В задании сказано, что я должен вести логирование действий пользователей в веб-приложении. Не могли бы мне объяснить, что от меня требуется? Мой проект имеет функционал. Регистрация и авторизация, пользователь может загружать файлы и эти файлы могут скачивать другие пользователи. Это я все сделал. Все работает. А что касается задачи логирования действий пользователя, я не понимаю, что мне нужно получить в готовом проекте. Если не сложно, объясните, пожалуйста, что я должен сделать. Наверное, с учетом того, что я ученик, и это первый мой проект. И тот, кто мне это задание дал, он это знает. В логе должна содержаться информация что user с id таким то сделал такой то запрос, получил такой то ответ. Правильно я понимаю суть задачи?

Comment: Лучше об этом спрашивать того, кто дал задание, а не незнакомцев в интернете.
Более того, хорошо заданные вопросы обычно положительно влияют на прохождение тестового.

Comment: `В логе должна содержаться информация что user с id таким то сделал такой то запрос, получил такой то ответ` - это постановщик задачи вам сказал? Потом при чем тут spring?

Comment: Делаю проект я в Spring. Нет задача была сделать логирование действий пользователя. Вот я и спрашивал, что под этим подразумевается?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что от Вас требуется вести учёт действий пользователей, например таких как:

1. Время входа/выхода из аккаунта
2. Время/название/вес файла при его загрузке
3. Скачивание пользователем других файлов (информация как во втором п-те)
4. Иные действия, которые предусмотрены в Вашем (напр-р изменение имени и прочего).

Т.е. Вам требуется записывать каждый шаг пользователей, для того, чтобы иметь возможность отследить действия, производимые пользователями.
Конечно всё зависит от поставленной задачи, есть небольшая статья по реализации журналирования на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/articles/521950/)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Comment: А еще вопрос один. Для этого достаточно через principal получать текущего авторизованного и в log.info() записывать нужную информацию? Я имею ввиду не нужно создавать какую то сущность дополнительную для этой задачи?

Comment: Я думаю, что это зависит от поставленной задачи. Точного ТЗ нету, поэтому как реализовывать, остаётся за Вами. Есть статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/articles/521950/), советую почитать, может найдется то, что пригодится Вам.

Comment: Спасибо больше еще раз)))

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, то прошу указать его как верным, спасибо!